# Why does this PHP function cycle endlessly?

Tags: php, cycle

```
function nonrecgen($min, $max, $amount) {
for($i=0;$i<$amount;$i++) {

$NrArray[$i] = rand($min,$max);
echo $NrArray[$i];
do  {
    for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++) {
      if ($NrArray[$j] == $NrArray[$i]) {
      $NrArray[$i] = rand($min,$max);   }     
                          }
       $Reccuring = false;
   if ($i > 0) {
    for($k=0;$k<=$i;$k++) {
      if ($NrArray[$k] == $NrArray[$i]) {
       $Reccuring = true;               }
                          }
               }
    }
while ($Reccuring = true);
                          }
Return $NrArray;                                        
                                        }

$Test = nonrecgen(0,1,2);
print_r($Test);
```

I wanted to look into how to generate an array of nonreccuring numbers and while this is certainly not the most efficient way I believe, I can't seem to figure out why it loops endlessly on the first iteration. I tried logical analysis over and over, but there has to be something I'm missing.

Comment: Who needs sensible indentation, after all.

Comment: FYI, this is called an *infinite loop*. Also, @andrewsi's solution is correct.

Comment: @rdlowrey indeed ... or contrivances like [a spelling checker](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recurring)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than the `=` to `==` you were also resetting the `$Recurring` in the wrong place:

```
<?
function nonrecgen($min, $max, $amount) 
{
    for($i=0;$i<$amount;$i++) 
    {
        $NrArray[$i] = rand($min,$max);
        do  
        {
            for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++) 
            {
                if ($NrArray[$j] == $NrArray[$i]) 
                {
                    $NrArray[$i] = rand($min,$max);  
                }     
            }
            if ($i > 0) 
            {
                for($k=0;$k<=$i;$k++) 
                {
                    if ($NrArray[$k] == $NrArray[$i]) 
                    {
                        $Reccuring = true;               
                    }
                }
            }
            $Reccuring = false;
        }
        while ($Reccuring == true);
    }
    return $NrArray;                                        
}
$Test = nonrecgen(0,2,5);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($Test);
?>
```

Answer (score 29):

```
do {
...
} while ($Reccuring = true);
```

Because your while statement sets $Reccuring to true, instead of evaluating it.

Try:

```
do {
...
} while ($Reccuring === true);
```

Comment: `===`? Would that be necessary for `true`. I have no clue about PHP, but the other answers only have `==`. If it is advisable/necessary it is probably worth elaborating on.

Comment: @BillWoodger - with this code, it won't make a difference, as he's explicitly using just `true` and `false`; I tend to use `===` as a default in my own code, just because it's a stricter check.

Answer (score 6):

You're currently assigning a value rather than checking (which will always be true).

Change it to:  `while ($Reccuring == true);`